# Conversion failed when converting date and /or time from character string C# asp.net-MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I Know this question has been asked many times, I've looked at all the answers and tried many things but I still have the same problem. It's a simple web application with asp.net MVC using ADO.net. I can read, create and delete so far without problem. I don't have a date format problem in creation. However, when I want to Edit(The data of the model to be modified is passed to the view), even if the same date is re-entered  in the same format I get the error message. Here is the method for updating in my persistence class:

```
public static void UpdateContact(Contact c) {
            string requete = "UPDATE Contact SET nom='@nom', Telephone='@telephone', 
                  Courriel='@Courriel', 
                  Datenaissance='@DateNaissance'," +
                " CodePostal='@CodePostal', StatutCivil='@StatutCivil' 
                             WHERE IdContact = @idContact";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(requete, conn);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("idContact", c.IdContact);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nom", c.Nom);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Telephone", c.Telephone);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Courriel", c.Courriel);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateNaissance", c.DateNaissance);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CodePostal", c.CodePostal);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("StatutCivil", c.StatutCivil);

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

In the database DateNaissance is `datetime2(7)` and in my model it's a `DateTime`. I paused the program before `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` to check the value of `c.DateNaissance` which was at the right format. Thank you in Advance!

EDIT: As I was reading my question I realised I put 
 comas in `DateNaissance='@dateNaissance'` I removed them and tested and I got this error :

```
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

**SOLVED :**  I lost 3 hours on something like that lol -.- It was a syntax error, that's how my query should have been written ( without commas):

```
string requete = "UPDATE Contact SET nom=@nom, Telephone=@telephone, Courriel=@Courriel, Datenaissance=@DateNaissance," +
            " CodePostal=@CodePostal, StatutCivil=@StatutCivil WHERE IdContact = @idContact";
```

Comment: Have you tried converting the data in the Date field before parsing that to the Parameter?

Comment: I think you need to convert date value at this line: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateNaissance", DateTime.Parse(c.DateNaissance));` or use `cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateNaissance", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = c.DateNaissance;`. Which field declared as `DateTime2` then?

Comment: `String or binary data would be truncated` => possibly you have `DateTime2` value larger than 7 in length. Try using field length larger than `datetime2(7)`.

Comment: I Can't use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateNaissance", DateTime.Parse(c.DateNaissance));` since `c.DateNaissance` is already `DateTime` Type. I tried this `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateNaissance", DateTime.Parse(c.DateNaissance));` but it doesnt workl neither.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I changed the column in database from `DateTime2(7)` to `DateTime`. Still I get `String or binary data would be truncated.`

Comment: Check other columns length as well, possibly you're having one or more columns having actual length less than inserted value in parameters, e.g. `nvarchar(10)` inserted with string which has 12 characters or something like that.

Comment: I checked, I'm Editing existing records which were inserted without problem. I just change one letter to see if the UPDATE works. Still the same problem

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto so with `DateNaissance='@dateNaissance'` I get a conversion problem  but with `DateNaissance=@dateNaissance` I get a truncated error. What do you this is my real issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED : I lost 3 hours on something like that lol -.- It was a syntax error, that's how my query should have been written ( without commas):

```
string requete = "UPDATE Contact SET nom=@nom, Telephone=@telephone, Courriel=@Courriel, Datenaissance=@DateNaissance," +
            " CodePostal=@CodePostal, StatutCivil=@StatutCivil WHERE IdContact = @idContact";
```

Answer (score 0):

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateNaissance", Convert.ToDateTime(c.DateNaissance));

Comment: it is already a DateTime. I don't have to convert it again. The error was in the QueryString I shouldn't write the variable with comas.